# NodeJS terminate setTimeout() when request ended

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

In the code below, setTimeout() keeps running after the client closes the request. How do I stop it?

```
function doSomething(callback){
    console.log('Doing something...');
    callback();
}

app.get('/', (req, res) => {

    function waitTilDone(){
        setTimeout(function(){
            doSomething(waitTilDone);
        }, 2000);
    }

    doSomething(waitTilDone)

});
```

Comment: You can bind an event on the `close` and `end` on the `req` to clear the timeout.

Comment: And/or `aborted`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Express's [`Request`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req) is an enhanced version of Node's [`IncomingMessage`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_incomingmessage), which has `close`, `end`, and `aborted` events. Hook to the most appropriate event(s) and clear the timeout. E.g., something like:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    var timer = 0;

    req.on('aborted', function() {
        if (timer) {
            clearTimeout(timer);
        }
    });

    function waitTilDone(){
        timer = setTimeout(function(){
            doSomething(waitTilDone);
        }, 2000);
    }

    doSomething(waitTilDone)

});
```